# Properties in spring boot project as dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot Web project that has a Spring Boot JPA project as a dependency like so:

```
spring_boot_web
|__.../application.yml
|
|__spring_boot_jpa
|  |__.../data.properties
|  |__.../data-test.properties
|  |__.../data-dev.properties
|  \__pom.xml
|
|__pom.xml
```

Web project uses the default application.yml file and jpa uses a properties file as yml are not supported by `@PropertySource` annotation.

I can run them alone flawlessly but when I try to include the jpa inside web there are problems creating the beans related to db. Is there any way to have those project running their own config files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got it working. As the JPA project does not stand on its own (only for testing purposes) I just left some properties for the profiles I want that project to run standalone and then the *main* properties file under the web project. The structure is as follows:

```
spring_boot_web
|__.../application.yml
|
|__spring_boot_jpa
|  |__.../application-test.yaml
|  |__.../application-dev.yaml
|  \__pom.xml
|
|__pom.xml
```

And then I made sure that there was only one `@SpringBootApplication` in between both projects altogether.

Also keep in mind that the main `@SpringBootApplication` has to be in a package in common for both projects:

```
spring_boot_web
|__foo.bar.core
|  \__SpringWebApplication.java <- main @SpringBootApplication
|
|__foo.bar.core.web
|  \__...
|
\__spring_boot_jpa
   \__foo.bar.core.services
      \__...
```